# var keyword guessing VS 2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio, var

This code works fine:

```
Process v = Process.GetProcessById(6752); // firefox 
Console.WriteLine(v);
ProcessThreadCollection th = v.Threads;
foreach (ProcessThread pt in th)
{
    var info = string.Format("-> Thread ID: {0}\tStart Time: {1}\tPriority: {2}",
        pt.Id, pt.StartTime.ToShortTimeString(), pt.PriorityLevel);
    Console.WriteLine(info);
}
```

But do not work this one:

```
Process v = Process.GetProcessById(6752); // firefox 
Console.WriteLine(v);
ProcessThreadCollection th = v.Threads;
foreach (var pt in th)  // var instead of ProcessThread
{
    var info = string.Format("-> Thread ID: {0}\tStart Time: {1}\tPriority: {2}",
        pt.Id, pt.StartTime.ToShortTimeString(), pt.PriorityLevel);
    Console.WriteLine(info);
}
```

`pt` in second assumed as `object` by compiler and don't compile of course.

Why assumed element of `ProcessThreadCollection` as `object` instead of `ProcessThread` by compiler?

Comment: Please see my answer for the underlying reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ProcessThreadCollection`'s enumerator comes from `ReadOnlyCollectionBase` whose enumerator is `IEnumerator` rather than `IEnumerator<ProcessThread>`.

`GetEnumerator` in `ReadOnlyBaseCollection` is a virtual method which, by default, returns `this.InnerList.GetEnumerator()` - InnerList is an `ArrayList`. `ProcessThreadCollection` doesn't override this method which is why you are getting object rather than `ProcessThread`.

The best solution to this would be (as I'm sure you're aware) to simply do this:

```
foreach(ProcessThread pt in th)
```

Answer (score 9):

`Process.Threads` is an `IEnumerable`, not an `IEnumerable<ProcessThread>`.  The code in your first snippet is casting each object in the `IEnumerable` to `ProcessThread`.  The code in your second snippet isn't casting the code at all, and is instead using the actual types of the objects, which is `object`.